# iOS 7 receiving airdrop files

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, file-sharing, airdrop

I'm trying to get my app to register when files are airdropped.

According to apple

```
To receive files sent via AirDrop, do the following:

In Xcode, declare support for the document types your app supports. (Xcode adds the appropriate keys to your app’s Info.plist file.) The system uses this information to determine whether your app can open a given file.
Implement the application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: method in your app delegate. (The system calls this method when a new file is received.)
```

I added the method to my app delegate. I'm running the ios7 GM on both devices.
I added the following to my app plist for doc types

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
            <array/>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>images</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.jpeg</string>
                <string>public.image</string>
                <string>public.png</string>
                <string>public.camera-raw-image</string>
                <string>public.content</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

As far as I can tell my application:openUrl method is never called. What Am I doing wrong? Do I have to enable something else in order to register for airdrop in my app?

Answer (score 2):

Even with other apps installed that I know for a fact will show up in the action sheet for an image sent over iMessage (Evernote, GoToMeeting, Halftone, DropBox), when someone sends me images over AirDrop it doesn't prompt me to choose an application to open it with. Since there's no documentation on this, I suspect Apple treats it the same as trying to have your app show up in the action sheet for images in mail attachments (they just don't show up). I imagine this is because they don't want users confused about images that are sent to them not appearing in the Photos app.

Comment: Is this true with the official release of iOS 7? I haven't seen such an option when receiving a file via airdrop.

Comment: @Alex1987 Not sure what you're asking - there is no option to send a file received over AirDrop to a specific application. An Application can register to handle a custom file type though, and if it's the only app registered I believe it would be started by iOS when the file is received via AirDrop (but I haven't tried to confirm)

Comment: what I meant is that whenever I receive a file via airdrop. The OS won't display a popover that asks with which app to open the file.

Comment: @Alex1987 What kind of file have you tested with?

Comment: That's my point - you're sending files that Apple wouldn't want the user to get confused about what they did with it (or if you like the paranoid theory, they want to trap the user in their apps and not yours).

Comment: Ya looks like when I tested my airdrop app using an excel file it prompted to open it in my app. Looks like apple reserves the right to intercept airdrops for media type file. One option is to convert the image to a custom format in your app and then send that to the other app and then decode.

Comment: IOS 13: still the same story, jpeg/png are caught by photos without a chance to have a choice